# How do I fix the "the entity does not have an ID" error?

Tags: 8

I need to save the configuration entity using the following code.
`$entity->save()` returns an error.

#### src\Form\ProtectPayMerchantProfileCreateForm

```
namespace Drupal\propay_api\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\propay_api\ProtectPayApi;

/**
 * Configure example settings for this site.
 */
class ProtectPayMerchantProfileCreateForm extends EntityForm {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'create_merchant_profile_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $account_number = '';
    parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['account-number'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Account Number'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => ($this->entity->account_number) ?? '',
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // @todo Add validations
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $entity = $this->entity;
    // Add configuration for certstr, termid, billerid and auth token.
    $elements = \Drupal::state();
    $values = $form_state->getValues();
    $data['ProfileName'] = 'ProPay';
    $data['PaymentProcessor'] = 'LegacyProPay';
    $data['ProcessorData'][] = [
      'ProcessorField' => 'certStr',
      'Value' => $elements->get('propay_api_cert_str'),
    ];

    $data['ProcessorData'][] = [
      'ProcessorField' => 'accountNum',
      'Value' => $values['account-number']
    ];

    $data['ProcessorData'][] = [
      'ProcessorField' => 'termId',
      'Value' => $elements->get('propay_api_term_id'),
    ];
    $data_string = $data;

    $protectPayAPI = new ProtectPayApi();
    $result = $protectPayAPI->setBillerId($elements->get('propay_api_biller_id'))
      ->setAuthToken($elements->get('propay_api_auth_token'))
      ->setMerchantProfileData($data_string)
      ->createMerchantProfile()
      ->getCreatedMerchantProfileInfo();

    $response = json_decode($result);
    if (($response->RequestResult) && $response->RequestResult->ResultCode == '00') {
      $entity->setAccountNumber($form_state->getValue('account-number'));
      $entity->setProfileId($response->ProfileId);
      $entity->save(); // It returns an error.
    }
    else {
      \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(
        t('Error occured with message:' . $response->RequestResult->ResultMessage . ' result code ' . $response->RequestResult->ResultCode));
    }
  }
}
```

#### src\Entity\ProtectPayMerchantProfile

```
namespace Drupal\propay_api\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase;

/**
 * Defines the ProtectPay Merchant Profile.
 *
 * @ConfigEntityType(
 *   id = "propay_api_merchant_profile",
 *   label = @Translation("ProtectPay Merchant Profile"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\propay_api\ProtectPayMerchantProfileListBuilder",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "add" = "Drupal\propay_api\Form\ProtectPayMerchantProfileCreateForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\propay\Form\ProtectPayMerchantProfileRenewForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\propay\Form\ProtectPayMerchantProfileDeleteForm",
 *     }
 *   },
 *   config_prefix = "merchant_profile",
 *   admin_permission = "administer site configuration",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "profile_id" = "profile_id",
 *     "account_number" = "account_number"
 *   },
 *   config_export = {
 *     "id",
 *     "label",
 *     "profile_id",
 *     "account_number"
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/config/development/propay-api/merchant-profile/{propay_api_merchant_profile}",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/config/development/propay-api/merchant-profile/{propay_api_merchant_profile}/delete",
 *     "enable" = "/admin/config/development/propay-api/merchant-profile/{propay_api_merchant_profile}/enable",
 *     "disable" = "/admin/config/development/propay-api/merchant-profile/{propay_api_merchant_profile}/disable",
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ProtectPayMerchantProfile extends ConfigEntityBase  {

  /**
   * ID.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * label.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $label;

  /**
   * The Merchant Profile ID.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $profile_id;

  /**
   * The Propay Account Number.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $account_number;

  public function setProfileId($profile_id) {
    return $this->profile_id = $profile_id;
  }

  public function setAccountNumber($account_number) {
    return $this->account_number = $account_number;
  }

  public function getProfileId($account_number) {
    $entities = $this->entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('propay_api_merchant_profile')
      ->loadByProperties(['account_number' => $account_number]);

    foreach($entities as $value) {
      return $value->profile_id;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Schema file

```
propay_api.merchant_profile.*:
  type: config_entity
  label: 'Protect Pay Merchant Profile'
  mapping:
    id:
      type: string
      label: 'ID'
    label:
      type: label
      label: 'Label'
    profile_id:
      type: integer
      label: 'Profile Id'
```